# I'm looking to make my discord.js bot invisible

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

```
client.user.setStatus('invisible')
client.on('ready',  async() => {
    console.log('I am online and ready to listen to commands!')
})
```

Does that work? Also I'm looking for a command that will do that like ;status dnd or ;dnd, pretty sure this code won't work:

```
client.user.setStatus('dnd')
```

> Ok, so I realised that the error is:
> https://pastebin.com/xtUZy0WW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `client.user.setStatus('invisible')` within the `ready` callback, otherwise `client.user` will be null. Other than that looks good :)

EDIT: looks like this

```
client.on('ready',  async() => {
    console.log('I am online and ready to listen to commands!')
    client.user.setStatus('invisible')

})
```